# How to deal with logging sensitive data (HTTP Authorization)?

Tags: java, security, logging, log4j

Say I have a webservice, which uses the HTTP Authorization header. I'm running some checks on the received headers, and if they don't pass, the service returns an error.

However, I'm having a bit of a problem, since I'd like to log what went wrong, but don't want to log any sensitive info 
(i.e., if the headers' check failed, it'd be useful to know what headers were received). Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
@Override
public Response service( 
        HttpHeaders headers,
        ...) {


    if (!checkRequestHeaders(headers)) {
        getLog().warn("Invalid request headers: "
                + "request=" + ui.getAbsolutePath()
                + "headers=" + headers);
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
    }
```

My first thought was to remove *only* the HTTP Authorization header from the log call (though since HttpHeaders are immutable, the code will be a bit more convoluted than I would like).

So now I'm wondering if there's a better way to exclude or obfuscate sensitive information from the logs, or if I'm overthinking this. Is there a common agreed way to do it? What do you usually do in situations like this?

Comment: I'd say you're overthinking this. Any sensitive information on the http header shouldn't be accessible without decryption.

Comment: You're overthinking this. You could prefix your sensitive headers and filter on that prefix to avoid logging them though.